# iOS 11 touch issue in the device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, touch, ios11, xcode9-beta

Developing an App with the Deployment Target of iOS 11.0 with Xcode 9-beta. My App is running fine in all iOS 11 iPhone SE/6/6s devices but when it comes for iPhone 6 Plus/ 7 plus /6s Plus the device touch is not working. (Unable to select/perform the options in the screen). Can anyone help me out from this problem.  Thanks in Advance.

**NOTE**: App is running fine in all the devices of iOS 10.3. This behaviour happens only in few devices of iOS 11.

Comment: I think it is iOS 11 beta version bug. From version iOS 11 beta 5, this issue is persist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented gesture recognizer in your app may be its detecting touch before screen UI element.

Use -(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldRecieveTouch....to define scenario e.g when button is clicked, gesture recognizer should not receive touch.